# How to have multiple entities mapped against one table?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm trying to use two different entities against the same table. The purpose of having two entities is to limit the amount of attributes in one of them, because on one of the edit forms it should only be possible to change a few of the attributes.

So in order to avoid having to have the non-editable attributes as hidden to preserve their values, I thought having a separate entity with just a portion of the attributes would be a good idea.

So I have one entity with all the attributes, and one with just some of the attributes. The problem is that I get this exception:

> `The entity types 'ApplicationMapping' and 'ApplicationMappingFull'
>   cannot share table 'ApplicationMapping' because they are not in the
>   same type hierarchy or do not have a valid one to one foreign key
>   relationship with matching primary keys between them.

The entity config classes look like this:

```
class ApplicationMappingFullConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<ApplicationMappingFull>  
{  
  public ApplicationMappingFullConfiguration()  
  {  
    ToTable("ApplicationMapping");  
    HasKey(p => p.Id);  
  }  
}  

class ApplicationMappingConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<ApplicationMapping>  
{  
  public ApplicationMappingConfiguration()  
  {  
    ToTable("ApplicationMapping");  
    HasKey(p => p.Id);  
  }  
}
```

How can I achieve what I'm trying to do? Is there a better/simpler way of doing it?

Thanks!

Comment: Does `ApplicationMappingFull` inherit from `ApplicationMapping`? Can you add the code for these classes to your question?

Comment: @HenkMollema No, there's no inheritance between the entities. They are separate entities, one have all the fields from the table, the other just having a few fields.

Comment: Just use two separate view models that both map back to the same entity.

Comment: Then the ViewModel approach would fit best here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend having a single entity mapped to the table, but create two 'view' entities that contain only those properties that the form requires.

These view entities could contain methods to map data entered back to the underlying entity.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a go at this method.

Comment: You might want to google for MVVM (Model - View - View Model) pattern, as this is what you are looking at here.

Answer (score 3):

It seems what you're looking for is TPH (Table Per Hierarchy). This is an relational inheritance pattern where a class and all it's subclasses share the same table and is supported natively by Entity Framework. In fact, if all you do is have one entity inherit from another, Entity Framework deploys this pattern by default. You don't need to do anything special at all.

However, there's a condition: since the properties on the base class must be enough on their own to be able to successfully save the row to the database, all your subclass properties *must* be optional -- at least on a database level. You could always enforce one or more properties to be required through the frontend user interface.

**UPDATE**

Expanding on my comment below, if all you're looking to do is return a subset of data from the table, then you already have all the tools you need. You don't need two separate entities, just one entity (in this case, your `ApplicationMappingFull` class) and then you can use LINQ to return only those columns you need.

```
db.ApplicationMappingFulls.Select(m => new ApplicationMappingViewModel
    {
        SomeProperty = m.SomeProperty,
        OtherProperty = m.OtherProperty
    });
```

Behind the scenes, EF will issue a query that will only select the `SomeProperty` and `OtherProperty` columns, because that's all that's needed. Your view model would not be connected to EF at all; it's just a class to hold the data returned by EF.

Comment: Hey, I tried to use inheritance, but now I get an exception that says I need a "Discriminator" column. I understand the purpose of this column, but there's no difference between the base class and the sub-class. I just want to be able to on one occasion retrieve a row from the table and represent it by an object with just a few of the columns, and on another occasion get the same row with all columns.. The data is the same in both occasions, and all rows in the table are of the same type.

Comment: If you're just talking about wanting to display a lesser amount of information from your database, you shouldn't be dealing with two entities at all. With LINQ you can select just the columns you want, and EF will actually issue that at a database level. Then you can either return an anonymous object of just those properties, or better, map it to a view model.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to have one class derive from the other, and hide or otherwise neuter the fields you dont wish to allow edit.

As an example...

```
class Full {
  public string ValueA {get;set;}
}

class Limited : Full {
  public new string ValueA {get; private set;}
}
```

This is admittedly not the greatest solution, but another choice you can use.

Answer (score -1):

You question has the answer.

> ```
> The entity types 'ApplicationMapping' and 'ApplicationMappingFull' cannot share table 'ApplicationMapping'
> ```

When you map an entity type to the table, you are defining the schema for the table. As you said, you have one entity with all the attributes, and one with just some of the attributes. When you map an entity to the table, you need to map all the columns of the table.

So in one line, "It is not possible".

**To achieve the solution of your problem**, you can do what Paddy suggested. Else you can create a base class with minimum required attributes then extend that class and add remaining attributes. While passing the model to the view, pass the base class object. However you can use extended class object while fetching the record from database.